# ResultSet not contain new inserted row

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working with Oracle Database 10g, java and try to use ResultSet to insert new row.

I have object of ResultSet which is updateble and insensitive in direction meaning that you can traverse in any direction.

When I insert row in ResultSet using moveToInsertRow, insertRow, and setter method, the row is inserted in Database, but while traversing ResultSet, I am not able to view newly inserted row

Can any one help me.

My Code is :

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
public class TestResultSet{

public static void main(String...args){
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe", "system", "admin");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select EnrNo, Name, Gender, DOB From Student");
        int i;
        while(rs.next()){
            for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ", ");
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Inserting New Row
        rs.moveToInsertRow();
        rs.updateLong(1, 117020365276L);
        rs.updateString(2, "Ashfaq");
        rs.updateInt(3, 1);
        Date d = new Date();
        rs.updateDate(4, new java.sql.Date(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay()));
        rs.insertRow();
        //New Row Insertion ends here

        rs.first(); //Moving to first row
        do{
            for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)  //Index starts from 1, not from 0
                System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ", ");
            System.out.println();
        }while(rs.next());
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
}
}

/*
Student Table Schema
EnrNo Numeric(12) Primary Key
Name varchar2(25);
Gender Numeric(1);
DOB date
*/
```

Comment: Get a new `ResultSet` by executing your statement, then print it again.

Comment: Can't it be a inefficient solution, if you have big database then each time you enter new record, you have to fetch all rows again

Comment: It could be *inneficient* but that's how it works. Note that the new row has been added to the database, **not to the current rows recovered from database**. So, in order to recognize the new row, you must do another read to your table(s).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the new row has been added to the database, **not to the current rows recovered from database**. So, in order to recognize the new row, you must do another read to your table(s). It could be *inneficient* (since it depends on how many rows and how complex your query is) but that's how it works.

Knowing this, your code should be like this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select EnrNo, Name, Gender, DOB From Student");
int i;
while(rs.next()) {
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ", ");
    System.out.println();
}
//Inserting New Row
rs.moveToInsertRow();
rs.updateLong(1, 117020365276L);
rs.updateString(2, "Ashfaq");
rs.updateInt(3, 1);
Date d = new Date();
rs.updateDate(4, new java.sql.Date(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay()));
rs.insertRow();
//New Row Insertion ends here

//Moving to first row of the current recovered resultset
//thus not working as expected
//rs.first();

//close the resultset
rs.close();
//retrieve the rows from database again
rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select EnrNo, Name, Gender, DOB From Student");
do{
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)  //Index starts from 1, not from 0
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ", ");
    System.out.println();
} while(rs.next());
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge, but I assumed that ResultSet of Java is working same as Dataset of VB.Net and that's the reason why I have asked this question

Answer (score 1):

I remember there were third party libraries that supported the functionality you are looking for, they are pretty expensive.

In general, yes, you will have to refetch. However, you can be smart about it: you can intelligently partition your query to fetch only a few hundred rows

- e.g. by using two tables, one for production data, other for new
  data, and sometimes merging them (you can use in-memory tables for the new data, and you can create cross-table views, if needed, although not neccessary)
- you can create an autoincrement index, and fetch only the latest rows,
- or you can use `ROWNUM` in Oracle, `SELECT TOP` in SQL Server, `LIMIT` in MySQL, etc.
- and of course, you can implement a custom database driver :-)

In general, if you fetch more than a few hundred rows regularly, something is wrong, and maybe you should reconsider your client side interface and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A `ResultSet` that is [`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) is not meant to detect updates to the underlying database (that is what the *insensitive* means here). If you want the `ResultSet` to detect changes, then you should use [`TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE).

However as the changes usually occur in a different transaction, I believe most databases are unable to offer `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, and if they can then they probably only allow you to see changes to the data of the selected rows, but not detect additional (or removed) rows.

If you try to use `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, you might want to check if your database actually supports that type (eg using [`DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#supportsResultSetType%28int%29)). Or by checking if the created `ResultSet` is actually of the specified type (the JDBC spec allows drivers to 'downgrade' type and/or concurrency if it isn't supported).

You might also want to check [`DatabaseMetaData.ownInsertsAreVisible(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#ownInsertsAreVisible%28int%29) and related methods for your specific database and driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String query = "Select EnrNo, Name, Gender, DOB From Student";
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS); 
    // change this to reflect your specific situation
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {                
        String EnrNo = rs.getString("EnrNo");
        String name = rs.getString("Name");
        String gender = rs.getString("Gender");
        String date = rs.getString("DOB");
        System.out.println(EnrNo + "\t" + name + "\t" + gender + "\t" + date);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// make sure you add these as your class variables:
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
```